# Gimp Drop Shadow unbound variable: WHITE-MASK

Tags: gimp, drop-shadow

Running Drop Shadow with:

[image]

Error: eval: unbound variable: WHITE-MASK

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like the standard drop-shadow script in Gimp 2.8 or Gimp 2.10 (different ordering of parameters, and the standard Gimp script has no lighting angle or layer mode parameters)

In neither Gimp 2.8 nor Gimp 2.10 I can find a `WHITE-MASK` constant, the closest being `ADD-WHITE-MASK` which is used in `(gimp-layer-create-mask layer mask-type)` (and is `0`).

Comment: I don't know what to say. I'm running 2.10 under Ubuntu 19.10. After reading your comment, I uninstalled and reinstalled the gimp package and the problem remains the same. Do you have any further advice for me?

Comment: I'm running 2.10.14 and the drop-shadow script (the "legacy" filter, since "Drop shadow" is now a GEGL filter) is different. Did you import a script a long time ago and forgot about it? If so it is in your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/) and remains between reinstalls (reinstalls do not reset the profile). Otherwise search in `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/script` and use `dpkg -S /path/to/file` to find from which package it comes from.

Comment: Probably. THanks for the assist.

Comment: It took a couple of tries, but I deleted all of the items in the directory you specified and then uninstalled and reinstalled. I think I had an install using the regular package and then a snap version and perhaps these were warring. I uninstalled them both, rebooted, and then installed using the Ubuntu Software application and now it appears to be working.

Comment: A bit violent to erase everything, an inspection in the `scripts` directory could have been enough :)